# Which is more effecient way of checking if count() function is not empty

Tags: php, performance

I'm having a code review on my peer and my peer come up with a question above.

Which is efficient:

**CODE A**

```
if (count($arr) != 0) {
   // *Code Here*
}
```

**CODE B**

```
if (count($arr) > 0) {
  // *Code Here*
}
```

Hope someone could do some explanation!

Comment: Both achieve identical results, and there is no performance difference between them, so each is equally correct.... have you considered `if (!empty($arr)) { ... }` which would be marginally more performant, though it's still a micro-optimisation

Comment: @MarkBaker can you provide good links so I can have more readings about micro-optimisation.

Comment: May be you are asking about their efficiency, not correctness, right? Your title and body question are different, which might confuse people.

Comment: @manetsus My question is updated

Comment: [micro-optimisation](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `count($arr)` represents the number of elements in an array and the number of elements in an array is always 0 or higher, `count($arr) > 0` and `count($arr) != 0` always produce the exact same output. That output is always `TRUE` whenever your array is not empty, and `FALSE` when it is empty.

With respect to performance, there's no noticeable difference. However, you could gain a minor performance benefit by doing this instead :

```
if (!empty($arr)) {
  // *Code Here*
}
```

Here, the output is also always `TRUE` whenever your array is not empty, and `FALSE` when it is empty. However, it is less *expensive* to do a test whether an array is empty than to count the number of elements of an array.

Comment: May be OP asked about the efficiency, not correctness. He already knows that both are correct!

Comment: @manetsus : The literal question is `Which is correct?` There's no mention of efficiency.

Comment: Well, this may technically answer the question, but have a look on the title.

Comment: @manetsus : Fair enough - My latest update does address performance